# VBA Dictionary is Duplicating Keys

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

having trouble and need some help. I have created a simple example to learn dictionaries in VBA and have already run into an issue. I have the following set up:

[image]

I am trying to loop over the keys, adding in the key and item. If the key exists, I want to add the item to it. What is happening instead is that the Key's get duplicated. In the example below, I end up with 2 keys for Apples instead of 1. What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated. Relevant code below:

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wkb.ActiveSheet

'clearing old totals
ws.Range("C8:C9").ClearContents

Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

For i = 3 To 6
    If dict.Exists(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "doesnt exist, adding " & ws.Cells(i, "B")
        dict.Add ws.Cells(i, "B"), ws.Cells(i, "C")
    ElseIf dict.Exists(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) Then
        MsgBox "exists"
        dict.Item(ws.Cells(i, "B")) = dict.Item(ws.Cells(i, "B")) + ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
    End If
Next i

MyArray = dict.Keys
MsgBox "Keys are: " & Join(MyArray, ";")

MyArray = dict.Items
MsgBox "Items are: " & Join(MyArray, ";")

For Each k In dict.Keys
    ws.Range("C8") = ws.Range("C8") + dict.Item(k)
    If k = "Apples" Then
        ws.Range("C9") = ws.Range("C9") + dict.Item(k)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't duplicate, but you may need to normalize case and\or trim the whitespace from the input.

Comment: Yeah I thought that could be the issue but the two "Apples" entries are identical ... no white space to trim, case the same, etc.

Comment: As @Comintern already pointed out: keys in dictionaries are unique and cannot duplicate. So, maybe there is a character in `Apple` which seems like `Аpple` but isn't? Compare the two posted `apples` here and you'll see that the first `A` is a `ChrW(65)` and the second `А` is in fact a `ChrW(1040)` which looks like an `А` but is actually derived from the Cyrillic alphabet.

Comment: I think @YowE3K hit the nail on the head with the .Row property issue and that this is the difference between the two cells. I can assure the contents are identical. Once I made the change to .value everything is working correctly. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are currently adding the cell as the key, rather than the `Value` of the cell, and cell B6 is not cell B3 - they have different `.Row` properties at least.

You should change your code to:

```
For i = 3 To 6
    If dict.Exists(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "doesnt exist, adding " & ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
        dict.Add ws.Cells(i, "B").Value, ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
    ElseIf dict.Exists(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) Then
        MsgBox "exists"
        dict.Item(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) = dict.Item(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) + ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks @YowE3k really appreciate the help and explanation!

Comment: @CodinglyClueless This is another reason why we shouldn't rely on `.Value` being the default property of a `Range` object - the key in a dictionary can be a `Range` **or** a `String` (or whatever) and so it decided to use the object itself as the key and had no need to use the default property of the object.

Comment: Great to know! Thank you!